# Internship and a full-time job at the same company on my resume

Tags: resume, internship

I have worked at a company for 6 years. Some months during the beginning of my career, I was on a paid internship with the same company.

During my internship I had the same duties (same projects and kind of job) I also had after my internship. The only difference is that I wasn't responsible for my actions cause I was "in training" and the chief engineer was my supervisor.

I have a section on my resume "work experience" that lists all the points of my experience, sorted by company name. As long as I didn't have different duties during my internship, I'm not sure how to write that because I can't distinguish some different kind of skills I developed during that period.

So, is it okay to just put a line like "internship" with a "Junior" title or "in training" or something like that in that case?

Answer (score 3):

#### Distinguish based on title not job description

Specify the internship separately from the job on your resume. It doesn't matter whether the job responsibilities changed much or not between designations. Your resume also speaks about how you progressed within the same company.

Being on internship followed by a full-time job conveys more information to someone reading your resume. It also reflects that you successfully completed your "internship" and were able to secure a full-time job.

Comment: If I distinguish my internship in a seperated title I won't have anything new points to mention into it. That's why I just put "internship" in my last point under that job at the company

Comment: @MrBit You can certainly mention that you were a trainee and that's a useful bit of information.

Comment: I did, I just put it as a point under all the experience I've gained during my tenure at the company. I'm just not sure if it is okay as it is. I can distinguish that period of time  in a new section like "internship (with dates)" but I can't put the same experience twice or leave it empty.

Comment: @MrBit Distinguish based on time (with dates) and under experience mention that you were working as a trainee under a mentor.

Comment: is this a must to do? Could I just leave it as a point under the list of experience at the company? I'm not sure what is better...

Comment: @MrBit Is it a must do? No. It's totally your call whether to mention it or not. It's however better to mention it as it provides more information about you.

Answer (score 1):

I would just put it in as 6 years experience at the company without special mention of the internship.

When a new colleague started at our job my teamlead specifically told him it could take at least 6 to 9 months just to get to know how we work and get started on actually writing code on his own. Up until then he is to figure out what to do on some small "starter" project (low priority, low impact project), where he was to ask us information and could only commit code after someone had revied it first.

This doesn't sound much different from an internship right? Yet he was hired as a full employee and those were the actual initial expectations.

---

The only reason to write it explicitly as internship is if you are again aplying for an internship at a new company and want to show that this has worked favorably for both you and the company you worked at. Usually with over 5 years of experience, people no longer search for internships, but rather immediately for a full time job.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put a subtitle in the same branch of information.

> Internship (x time)
>
> > Job (x time)
> >
> > > Description of duties and experience.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how I've written this type of career progression on a resume:

Vice President/Senior Director/Manager/Staff, Norton Product Management 1996 to 2009

Look at the [actual resum](https://avidcareerist.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/General-Manager-Resume.pdf)e to better see the formatting.